# Executing simultaneous curl calls from bat script

Tags: batch-file, curl

I put together a basic batch script that grabs words from a txt file and executes `curl` on three urls with the `search_word` being the search paramater. The results are placed in a html page. However, I am running into an issue.. it a slow process. How can I execute the `curl` simultaneously for the three `urls`?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set OUTPUT_FILE=test.html
for /f %%i in (search_words.txt) do (
    curl -k -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" http://www.example.com/search?q=%%i >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
    curl -k -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" http://www.example2.com/search?q=%%i >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
    curl -k -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" http://www.example3.com/search?q=%%i >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
)
```

Comment: `start curl ..` instead? batch files aren't threaded, and each command will block until it completes. but note that you'll probably end up with garbage in your output file, since you'll undoubtedly have multiple curl processes dumping their output into the same file at the same time.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the feedback. I think I followed most of what you mentioned. Could you show me exactly what you meant with starting`curl` and dumping results in a file?